# Change the language of UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localization, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there any way to forcefully change the language of `UIImagePickerController` while app is running?

I've used localization in my project, for `Arabic` and `English`. But when I change app language while it is running, it works perfectly but it does not change camera and photo gallery language until I restart the phone and similar is the case with `UINavigationController` Push/Pop animations.

Here is my code for localization

```
func localizedString(key: String) -> String {
        if let lang = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("language") as? String {
            let language = lang
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(language, ofType: "lproj")
            let bundle = NSBundle(path: path!)
            let string = bundle!.localizedStringForKey(key, value: nil, table: nil)
            return string
        } else {
            return NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
        }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your language code in below code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standarUserDefaults] setValue:@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standarUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Thanks ManiaChamp, I'm already doing same, it works fine but only if you restart app.